# attempt to decode jsonp response

Tags: python, json, jsonp

I am fairly new to programming, so go easy on me!

this is the response from the server

```
s
'jsonp1369552036642({"code":0,"ret":{"percentage":100}})'
```

Now, while the jsonpnumbers preceeds the response, python wont let me use json.load(s).

if I can obtain

```
{u'code': 0, u'ret': {u'percentage': 100}}
```

I can sort myself out from there!

I want to know if there are any tricks or codes that can get to the solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use JSONP in the first place.  Try omitting the callback parameter.

Comment: Wish I could, but that is the standard response from the server. The callback is a necessary evil unfortunately

Comment: then remove everything up to the first '(' and the last ')' as well.

Comment: Jsonp is made so you can automatically call a javascript function from the json response. Hence the function name jsonp1369552036642 and why its enclosed in parentheses.  You would need to parse out those characters and leave only the pure JSON to use that method is my suspicion.